# parfor in Matlab: The variable in a parfor cannot be classified

Tags: matlab, parfor

I have the following `parfor` loop which I would like to execute.

I am getting the error:

```
Error: File: Coords_to_distances4.m Line: 32 Column: 9
The variable nr in a parfor cannot be classified.
```

which points to the last line of the inner for loop.

`nr` is declared and initialised outside of the loop, and I can't see any other link between the variable indexing or such that all of the other solutions talk about.

```
coords = ... %nx2 array of x and y coordinates
n = length(coords); %n can be up to several million
dr = 0.01; %distance resolution for upcoming calculations

nr = [zeros(200000,1)]; %array to hold counts of distances up to maximum of 200000*dr 

parfor i = 1:n
    for j = i+1:n
        dx =  coords(i,1) - coords(j,1); %get separation in x
        dy =  coords(i,2) - coords(j,2); % and in y

        r = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); %calculates Pythagorean distance
        nbin = floor(r/dr + 0.5); %rounds to the nearest integer
        nr(nbin) = nr(nbin) + 1; %uses the distance as an index to the array to incremenet  
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to parallelise this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to limitations of `parfor` 
In the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/nested-parfor-loops-and-for-loops.html), "For proper variable classification, you must define the range of a for-loop nested in a parfor-loop by constant numbers or variables"